# Compilation time - closures - Scheme

Tags: scheme

Can you tell me please what is the meaning of closures that their creation in compilation time?
For example,

```
(define nth-deriv
  (lambda(f n)
     (lambda (x)
          (if (= n 0) (f x) ( (nth-deriv (deriv f) (- n 1)) x))
))

(define deriv
   (lambda(f)
      (lambda(x)
         (/ (- (f (+ x dx))
                     (f x))
                 dx))))
```

I know that in definition time the first lambda in each function is evaluated (closure). what about compilation time?
The expression:

```
(define five-exp(lambda(x)(* x x x x x)))
(define fourth-deriv-of-five-exp (nth-deriv five-exp 4))
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where is this expressed, and how?

Comment: Edited with expressions

Answer (score 0):

A closure is two things: code and an environment.  The environment is essentially a vector of values that are free in the lexical scope of the function.  When the code executes it will get some values from arguments and some values from the environment.  For example in your above `lambda with 'if' body` - the value of x is from the arguments and the values of `n`, `f`, `nth-deriv`, `deriv`, `=` and `-` come from the environment.

The compiler produces all the code at compile time and then at runtime produces the closure pairing the code with the environment.

Here is a quick example:

```
$ (define foo (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (y x))))
;; Address  : <unknown>
;; Label    : foo
;; Constants:
;;         0: #t
;;         1: (code none ...)
;; Code     :
;;         0: check 1 0
;;         3: get-loc 0
;;         5: closure 1 1
;;         8: return 1
;;          :
;; Address  : <unknown>
;; Label    : none
;; Constants:
;;         0: #t
;;         1: (<function> 14)
;; Code     :
;;         0: check 1 0
;;         3: get-loc-res 0 1
;;         6: get-env 0
;;         8: call-tail-slow 1
$
```

This shows byte-codes for a function `foo` and its returned `lambda`.  In `foo` there is a byte-code of `closure 1 1` which takes the code at constants index 1 and the 1 values on the stack (the value of `x`) to create a closure and then return it.  The code for the `lambda` pushes a local value on the stack (`get-loc-res`), pushes a value from the environment (`get-env`) and then makes a call (`(y x)`).

Comment: Which implementation do you use that output those stats?

Comment: My own; but unavailable.

Comment: Thank you. Which lambda's are closures that their creation time is in compilation?

Comment: Both are closures.  I didn't show the assembler output for creation of the closure that gets bound to `foo`.  The closure for `foo` is created as part of the REPL.

Comment: Please 'up-vote' if this answer was useful; mark as 'answered' if you are satisfied.